# Create image layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-imageview

I am developing an application. The need is as, i want to create a layout as shown in figure :

[image: Layout]

In this, I took a relative layout to which I had given an image as background.
The image is not having red dot (buttons).

I placed the red button as image button at fix position. When i run it on my galaxy s2 it looks fine and work fine too.

But when I tested this layout on my LG optimus L3 E400. The red buttons are not on their position as i set.

The code of layout is :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_navigationbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/navigationbar"
        android:text="@string/string_map"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textIsSelectable="false" />


    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textview_navigationbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50sp"
        android:background="@drawable/map">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton_1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_2" />        

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebutton_3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imagebutton_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dip"
            android:background="@drawable/button_3" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my LG Optimus L3 E400 it looks like :

[image: Layout 2]

The red buttons are not on position.
I don't want to use map view for this as i don't know and never used it.

Please guide me how to move out of this problem. As how to create layout for maximum resolution and screen support.

Comment: it wont be the same .. because the device sizes are different so will get vary in that position..

Comment: @itsrajesh4uguys : so how to over come of it.

Comment: you need to draw pro grammatically using canvas or some thing like that...

Comment: better you can go with the android map (you can use zoom to particular positions ).. and you can mark the overlays in particular positions(using lat and long ). then it will be the same in all devices.. even click event will work

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to create a custom view that holds the image (bitmap) and the buttons on top of it, and use `onDraw` method to draw your buttons, and analyse the coordinates on `onTouch` to create your touch events.

If you maintain your image's aspect ration (width:height) you can easily map the buttons to a suitable location using scaling.

Here is a list of custom views examples:

- [Android Developer's Custom Views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html)
- [With Touch handling](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/05/custom-view-with-user-interaction.html)
- [Another example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)

You can also use `AndEngine` a 2D graphics/gaming engine for android, and it will take care of the scaling for you.

Take a look here : [official website](http://www.andengine.org/blog/) , [examples](https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/)

Answer (score 2):

This can be done best with Canvas.

Or the easier way to do this would be edit the image and add those red dots in image itself.

you can use onTouchListener and in onTouch you can get the x and y coordinate to accomplish your task

Something like this:-

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY(); 
      //handle your events on basis of x and y
     }
```

This is'nt the best way to handle it. But should work.

Comment: If i added red buttons in image itself then how can i click on it.